# How do I use emacs on macos terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

I downloaded [Emacs for MacOS](https://emacsformacosx.com/tips) and created a file called emacsclient using `ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient /usr/local/bin`

Then created a script called ec in my PATH with the contents

```
#!/bin/sh
which osascript > /dev/null 2>&1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs" to activate'
emacsclient -c "$@"
```

The above steps were from [Emacs for MacOS](https://emacsformacosx.com/tips)

I then set an alias using alias `emacs="emacsclient -t --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server"` so that i could call emacsclient using just emacs.

when I call emacs I get the message

`emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?`

`emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".`

`emacsclient: error accessing socket "/tmp/emacs1000/server"`

I am a beginner and don't really know much.
Thanks

Comment: `emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".` Did you try this?

Comment: -bash: M-x: command not found

Comment: Pretty sure it is an emacs command, not a bash one. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html

Comment: How do I do that? I really don't know what I'm doing. Sorry

Comment: M-x means press Meta (command or option, depends) and x in Emacs, or just put "(server-start)" in your init file.

Comment: It sounds like you've symlinked `emacsclient` without `emacs`.  In any case, you shouldn't be trying to start a server as your *first* attempt at running Emacs... just run it normally first, and experiment with the client/server aspect only if everything else is known to be working.

Comment: The confusion over `M-x` indicates that you're not familiar with emacs at all, so what you need to do before anything else is to run `emacs` (not your custom script; the *actual* `emacs` program) and then ask it to take you through the tutorial by typing `C-h t`.  Once you've gotten through the tutorial, you'll have some grounding for follow-up questions.

Comment: I guess I should also clarify that "typing `C-h t`" means "press and hold the `Ctrl` key, press and release the `h` key, then release the `Ctrl` key, and finally press and release the `t` key."

Answer (score 0):

The command `emacsclient -t --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server`will work only if you've started a emacs server first.

To launch a emacs server, execute the following command :

```
emacs --daemon
```

After that, the command `emacsclient -t` will open a new Emacs frame INSIDE the terminal. If you want to have an "outside the terminal" Emacs frame launch `emacsclient -n`.

What I recommend is to have the command `emacs --deamon` launch at startup, and I binded "Ctrl-Alt e" to `emacsclient -n` to launch new Emacs frame with a quick shortcut.

Finally, you can find a lot of information on the GNU documentation of Emacs, here is the page for the emacsclient command : [GNU's documentation on emacsclient](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html)